# App-Engine Connected Android Project: Does Google-Eclipse Plugin generate Client Endpoints for iOS and JavaScript in addition to the android api

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, google-cloud-endpoints, google-eclipse-plugin

**Old**

I need to work on the iOS version of my app. The App-Engine and Android portions are completed using the Google Eclipse Plugin (GPE). In the [Official Google Documentations](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/gen_clients#generating_a_discovery_doc_for_ios_using_maven) I am told the easiest way is to use maven. Does anyone know how I might add maven to the App-Engine portion of my “connected” project?

Apparently I only need to add the following one line in the maven file

```
mvn appengine:endpoints_get_discovery_doc
```

**Update**

Again, I need to get the iOS client for an endpoint project that I created with the Google Eclipse Plugin as an *App-engine Connected Android Project*. From eclipse I simply do `[Right Click] > Google > Generate Cloud Endpoint Client Library` and it generates the library for android. But now I just look in my war directory and I see three files: `myendpoint-1-rest.discovery`, `myendpoint-1-rcp.discovery`, `myendpoint-1-rest.api`.

Now this is a wild guess, but are these the files I need for iOS and JavaScript? Or must I follow the instructions in the official docs to get the discovery files for iOS? What I mean is I have not generated the files per the instructions but I have used the GPE for creating the endpoints for android. Does GPE create the necessary clients for iOS and JavaScript as well? I cannot find any documentation on that.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript client only [needs to include script https://apis.google.com/js/client.js](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js#enabling_a_javascript_client_for_endpoints). You can load your API using

```
gapi.client.load('api-name', 'v1', callback, 'https://app_id.appspot.com/_ah/api');
```

Objective-C client needs [some extra work after generating your discovery doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios).